# A question on my ability to import?

Tags: import, permissions

I cannot find a tab or any import button to import my data I have on excel. I'm not admin, but I have the ability to add cases, organisations and individuals. Do I have to be the admin in order to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need permissions like `import contacts` to import contacts. You will need to ask for that permission to be added to your current role.

The permissions for various import functionalities are defined in [`CRM/Core/xml/Menu/Import.xml`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/xml/Menu/Import.xml)